# how to save data in localstorage for further use?

Tags: javascript, trie

how can i save the data in localstorage each keyup and when i search again data will show from localstorage, this time do not sent any request for data from db.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#input_id').keyup(function (e) {
    var name = $('#input_id').val();
    var data = name.trim();
    var msg = $('#result');
    msg.empty();

    $.ajax({
      url: "search.php",
      method: "post",
      data: { input: data },
      dataType: "",
      success: function (name) {
      console.log(name);
      var getdata = JSON.parse(name);
      var z = getdata.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < z; j++) {
        if (getdata[j].surname) {
          var show_result = '<span id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + getdata[j].surname + '</span>';
          msg.append(show_result);
        } else {
          var show_result2 = '<span id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + '</span>';
          msg.append(show_result2);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Just use `localStorage.setItem(key, val)` to save the value and when you want to fetch it `localStorage.getItem(key)`.

Comment: can you help me to check , how to modify the code for check is this data already in localstorage? if not than data will retrieve from db.

Comment: `if (localStorage.getItem(<your_key>)) {//exist} else {//do not exist, retrieve from db}`

Comment: @ Sriped where should i add this condition before ajax call ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Check for the existence before your ajax request when you get your data values, and save your value if it does not exist in the ajax success callback.

Comment: is it right way ?   please can you help me to solve this ? Thanks 
var localdata = localStorage.getItem(data);
            if(localdata == null){
            $.ajax({
                url: "search1.php",
                method : "post",
                data :{
                    input : data},
                dataType: "",
                success: function(name) {
                    var getdata=JSON.parse(name);             
                    localStorage.setItem(data, name);
                    var s = getdata.length;

Comment: @ Sriped if possible can you do this for me kindly? Thanks

Comment: Do not compare local data with null but undefined. But the rest seems fine.

Comment: I made a post for you issue.

Comment: Thanks @ Striped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments:

```
$('#input_id').keyup(function (e) {
  var name = $('#input_id').val();
  var data = name.trim();
  var msg = $('#result');
  msg.empty();
  var localdata = localStorage.getItem('my_key'); 

  if (!localdata || localdata !== data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "search.php",
      method: "post",
      data: { input: data },
      dataType: "",
      success: function (name) {
        localStorage.setItem('my_key', name);
        console.log(name);
        var getdata = JSON.parse(name);
        var z = getdata.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < z; j++) {
          if (getdata[j].surname) {
            var show_result = '<span id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + getdata[j].surname + '</span>';
            msg.append(show_result);
          } else {
            var show_result2 = '<span id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + '</span>';
            msg.append(show_result2);
          }
       }
    }
  } else {
     // do something with local data
  }
...
```

Comment: @rai The probleme with this is that once you have saved a value to your localStorage, you will never request your db again. This should be fixed, but I let you find a way on your own ;) Come here again if you can't find it.

Comment: i can't find it. can you give me complete solution of it? Thanks

Comment: data can't save in localstorage. eack keyup it sent a request to the db for result.

Comment: Because each keyUp change the input, so each new update is different from the data saved in your localStorage. You should try to work with a submit action within a form instead of keyUp.

Comment: when i press a key all the relevant data will save in localstorage . so than if i  press a key which i previously do, data will show from localstorge , it will not request the db for data. if i press new key/letter , it will check first localstorage if the data is not found than it will go for database to search. Thanks a lot @ Striped

Comment: Are you sure to reset your input value after each keyUp ?

Comment: i will do it for search and i want to minimize the search time. thats why i put the values in localstorage for minimize the time and reduce calling database. do you understand what i want to do?

Comment: i do no want to reset my input value. if i press "M" ,  all the data which started with M will show and store in localstorage. after "M" if i click "A" than  all the data of "MA" will store in localstorage . it will go on this way. if i backspace than it will not call in db. Hope i make you understand waht i want to said. sorry for english .

Comment: Ok, this is absolutely not what we've done here. And the solution is much more complex than this. And I would not recommend you do to as you want because you would have a lot of data stored in your localStorage for each different `name`. You should try something else in my opinion.

Comment: i appreciate your  suggestion. i have 10 millions of name which i saved in my text files. i read my text file and show out put, if the data is not there than i go to db for more data. 
so is it possible to save some of data using this function in localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

use "localStorage.setItem(key, val)" to store data into local storage e.g.

```
localStorage.setItem("key1_name", username.firstname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Khan M said, use the localStorage methods ".setItem(key, value)" to save data and "getItem(key) to retrieve that specific key's value.

From what I see, you're generating several different variables each keyUp so you should be able to store all of that by simply making an object of the " val" parameter like this:

`localStorage.setItem(key, {...});`

To retrieve the whole object: `localStorage.getItem(key);`

To retrieve the value of a specific property inside the object: `localStorage.getItem(key.propertyName);`

Hope you find this answer useful and good luck!

Comment: Hello @AlejandroG, Welcome to SO, please take a look at this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in order to improve your formatting.